# stop and remove docker container based on Port assigned

Tags: docker, docker-container

Below code will stop and remove a Docker container -

```
docker rm -f CONTAINER_ID
```

However it require *Container ID*, which I take from running another code `docker ps` to get the ID that is using a typical port (*e.g. 0.0.0.0:8383->8383/tcp*) from the column *PORTS*.

I am looking for a way to bundle these 2 codes into a single one with *PORT* as variable so that I do not need to feed manually the container ID obtained from `PORTS`.

Is there any possibility?

Comment: You're wanting to write a script.   Read some shell programming tutorials.  There is no off the shelf command that does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
PORT=8383
docker container ls --format="{{.ID}}\t{{.Ports}}" |\
grep ${PORT} |\
awk '{print $1}'
```

The first command lists the running containers but only outputs the container ID and the ports. The result is piped into `grep` to grab the container of interest. The `awk` commands grabs the container ID.

#### Test

- Create 3 Nginx containers on `:7777`,`:8888`,`:9999`.
- Then, find the containers by their ports, stop and remove them.

```sh
for PORT in 7777 8888 9999
do
  docker run --detach --publish=${PORT}:80 nginx
done

docker container ls

for PORT in 7777 8888 9999
do
  echo "Looking for a container on port: ${PORT}"
  ID=$(\
    docker container ls --format="{{.ID}}\t{{.Ports}}" |\
    grep ${PORT} |\
    awk '{print $1}')
  echo "Found Container ID: ${ID}"
  echo "Stopping and removing it"
  docker container stop ${ID} && docker container rm ${ID}
done
```

Comment: One question though - which language this follows?

Comment: This is Bash on LInux.  What OS are you using?

Comment: mac-os and ubuntu 18

Comment: The Bash commands in my answer will work on Ubuntu and should run on MacOS (IIUC MacOS supports Bash too [currently]). There's nothing OS-specific in any of the Bash that I referenced.

Comment: Not correct! the ID will have a format of {{.ID}}\t{{.Ports}}  and if we supply that to docker it will show an error No such Container!